# Repeat a task using schtasks.exe in windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

I need to run a task every 10 mins from morning 9 AM to Evening 3 PM every weekday on my Windows XP. I have used the following command to do that but on Windows XP SP3 I think /RI option is unavailable.

`schtasks /Create /RU HS77 /RP  /SC DAILY /TN taskname /TR C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe /ST 15:10 /RI 10 /ET 15:31 /K /SD 09/07/2009 /ED 09/07/2009 /F`

Is there any way of doing it with command line (only command line).Please help me..Thanks in advance.

**My Requirement:**Run an exe every week day morning 9:00 am to 3:00 pm every 10 mins. Schedule it using a program or from bat file or command line only once.

**EDIT:**Ok Looks like I need to figure out a way. My main problem is the /ET option (End Time) is disabled in XP. So I am trying it through a batch file which will create scheduled task for tomorrow morning starting at 9:00 AM and a c program which will delete it when it is 3:00 PM and recreate the scheduled task at next day morning 9:00 am. And this process repeats. But here also System date format is spoiling the plot. I need to figure out a way.

Am I missing an easy way?(angry..haa).

Or else throw out the windows scheduler in dust bin and use any open source small foot print schedulers which can do the required work for me and we can package it with our application?Or do I need to write my own custom scheduler which can run in background? (this is a whole new question). If I need to write a command line custom scheduler how can I run it in background in XP. Or How can I run a scheduled task in background(I mean cmd.exe should not popup when it is running).

Sorry for too many questions. I am a bit frustrated. Please Understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible with schtasks in Windows XP. You could config it to run a VBScript every ten minutes and in that VBScript you can check weekday and time.

```
If WeekDay(Date,2)<6 Then
  t=Time
  If t>TimeValue("9:00:00 AM") and t<TimeValue("3:00:00 PM") Then
    Dim WSHShell
    Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WSHShell.Run "notepad.exe", 1, false
  End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks I can do this even with a c program. thank you very much  for your advice

Answer (score 3):

You just missed the /MO option.  Anyway, I hope you might have solved your problem by now. May be I am late.  But still....
So making it very simple, it looks like this
**schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 10 /tn calc /tr c:\windows\system32\calc.exe**
I am sure you can put in the other stuff to suit your needs.
Regards,
Amroz.